# Can you override a pure virtual function within the same class?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, overriding, virtual-functions

I would like to extend an abstract base class with a virtual function and keep the function name as virtual, but running code before and after the "possibly" overridden child function.

Here is an example:

I have a base class (interface) for things that can be drawn:

```
class IDraw {
    public:
        virtual void do_draw(Screen *scr) = 0;
};
```

I want to keep this interface in subclasses and be able to override it,
for example I have a class for a Game, which cleans the screen, draw stuff and than flip the display buffer:

```
class Game : public IDraw {
    public:
        // Keep the interface
        // This can be overridden by sub classes
        virtual void do_draw(Screen *scr) = 0; // (1)
    private:
        // But override the base class so if s.b. calls
        // do_draw from a IDraw pointer it executes this!
        void IDraw::do_draw(Screen *scr) override; // (2)
};

// Implementation of (2)
void Game::IDraw::do_draw(Screen *scr) {
    // Do stuff before like clear the screen
    scr->clear();
    // Call the method supplied by childs
    this->do_draw(scr); // (1)
    // Present the drawing
    scr->present();
}
```

Since I have code before and after the function supplied by the child I cannot simply override keeping it virtual because the child must decide if calling Game::do_draw() // (2) before or after.

I know I can simply call the function (2) with a different name, but since I need many class doing this kind of stuff it will end with plenty of names for the same concept.

Is there any way to do this sort of thing in C++11?

Comment: No. You can not override function with different name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to keep this interface in subclasses and be able to override it,

That will be already the case automatically, because you inherited it at the `public` access level.

> for example I have a class for a Game, which cleans the screen, draw stuff and than flip the display buffer ...
>   ...
>   Is there any way to do this sort of thing in C++11?

Completely independent of any c++11 particularities, just write an implementation for the abstract function declaration, and add an additional layer of indirection (aka the [Template Method Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method)):

```
class Game : public IDraw {
public:
    // Keep the interface
    // This can be overridden by sub classes
    void do_draw(Screen *scr) override {
         OnPreDraw(scr);
         OnDraw(scr);
         OnPostDraw(scr);
    }
protected:
    virtual void OnPreDraw(Screen *scr) {
       // Default implementation
       scr->clear();
    }
    virtual void OnDraw(Screen *scr) = 0; // << Class is still abstract
    virtual void OnPostDraw(Screen *scr) {
       // Default implementation
       scr->present();
    }
};
```

This would allow to inject any implementation of `Game` at that finer grained sequence of operations, but keep default behavior from the base class implementation.
Also the base class is still abstract and effectively forces any derived class to implement `OnDraw()`, which is effectively the same as `do_draw()`.

> but since I need many class doing this kind of stuff it will end with plenty of names for the same concept.

No. As far your *concept* just involves the operations

```
 OnPreDraw(scr);
 OnDraw(scr);
 OnPostDraw(scr);
```

in that sequence, that won't change for the whole class inheritance hierarchy anymore in future.

---

**To an extend:**

You can also do that with [Mixin pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) classes<sup>1</sup>

```
template<typename Derived>
class AbstractIDrawImpl : public IDraw {
    void do_draw(Screen *scr) override {
         static_cast<Derived*>(this)->OnPreDraw(scr);
         static_cast<Derived*>(this)->OnDraw(scr);
         static_cast<Derived*>(this)->OnPostDraw(scr);
    }

    // Expects public implementations
    void OnPreDraw(Screen *scr) {
       // Default implementation
       scr->clear();
    }
    // Just no default implementation for 
    //    void OnDraw(Screen *scr) << Class is still abstract
    void OnPostDraw(Screen *scr) {
       // Default implementation
       scr->present();
    }
};
```

The above mixin example can be bound to any implementation of `IDraw` that provides `public` functions for `OnPreDraw()` , `OnDraw()` and `OnPostDraw()`:

```
class MyGame : public AbstractIDrawImpl<MyGame> {
public:
    // IDraw interface implementation
    void OnPreDraw(Screen *scr) {
        // Call base class implementation
        AbstractIDrawImpl<MyGame>::OnPreDraw(scr);
        // E.g fill my background here
    }
    void OnDraw(Screen *scr) {
        // For each game entity call 
        // IDraw::do_draw(scr);
        for(auto drawableEntity : drawableEntities_) {
            drawableEntity->do_draw(scr);
        }
    }
    // Skip implementation of OnPostDraw()
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IDraw>> drawableEntities_;
};
```

---

<sup>1)</sup>
That pattern is well described with Alexei Andrescou's [**Policy based design paradigm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C%2B%2B_Design) and heavily used with [**Microsoft's ATL**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ax346b7.aspx).

Comment: That's what I ended up using, but I was wondering if there was a way to avoid many function names for the same thing, for ex it won't be the same extending IDraw or Game thus if I decide to change to Game the parent I have to take care of changing the override names accordingly

Comment: @DarioDF Well, that's the best pattern to do that AFAIK. Another option might be to go into the direction of CRTP and static polymorphism / mixins. I have doubt's that's worth it. That pattern well does what you want, and just adds another level of indirection for deriving classes.

Comment: @DarioDF I've extended my answer a bit.